# How to use universal link for reset password in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, swift5, ios-universal-links

I’m using Universal link to achieve forgot password functionality in my app

When user click on forgot password we take email input & based on that generate link like below & send email, over that link I want that my app open reset password screen

`https://www.domain.in/resetpassword?emailId=test@gmail.com&deviceId=udid`

on developer.apple.com I enabled associate domain & add entitlements to app & add domain in capabilities section

[image]

Url handlers also added to app delegate

AASA file is also validate successfully with https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": “teamId.com.organization.appname”,
      "paths": ["https://www.domain.in/*”]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

still the link open on safari.

Something I forget to add or may be paths key value in AASA file is wrong ?

I prefer following link for implement universal link,
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: Remove www from associated domain entitlement and set path as "paths": ["*”]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add meta tag on your server where AASA file is uploaded

Example for meta tags :-

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=yourAppStoreID, app-argument=ThisPagesUrl>">
```

or

```
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
```

Comment: I try both solution still url redirecting to safari

Comment: Also for the first time it will redirect to the safari, user has to click on the web to open the app for the first time, next time onwards it will redirect to app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter your Associated Domain without "www", as: "applinks:domain.in"
2. In AASA (apple-app-site-association) file you can use "*" as a wildcard to enable all paths in a directory.
   Write down this way:

   {

   ```
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "teamId.com.bundleId.of.your.app",
            "paths": ["*"]
        }]
    }
   ```

   }